# In LibreOffice, how to connect to Oracle Database using Basic only

Tags: database, oracle, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base

I am trying to import Oracle data into my OfficeBase data base (FireBird). My goal is to open a record which connects directly to oracle like this:

1. connect to the oracle database using a proper connection string
2. get to the data with the appropriate SQL
3. cycle through the records using loop

Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer:

```
Sub Main
Dim oParms() As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    sUser$ = "uid"
    sPass$ = "pwd"
    sURL$ = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
    oManager = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.sdbc.DriverManager")
    AppendProperty(oParms(), "user", sUser)
    AppendProperty(oParms(), "password", sPass)
    AppendProperty(oParms(), "JavaDriverClass", "org.postgresql.Driver")
    oCon = oManager.getConnectionWithInfo(sURL, oParms())
    oStatement = oCon.CreateStatement()
    sSQL = "select * from table order by id desc"
    oResult = oStatement.executeQuery(sSQL)
    Do While oResult.next()
        s = oResult.getString(3) 
        print s
    Loop
    oCon.close()
End Sub

Sub AppendProperty(oProperties(), sName As String, ByVal oValue)
    AppendToArray(oProperties(), CreateProperty(sName, oValue))
End Sub

Sub AppendToArray(oData(), ByVal x)
    Dim iUB As Integer 'The upper bound of the array.
    Dim iLB As Integer 'The lower bound of the array.
    iUB = UBound(oData()) + 1
    iLB = LBound(oData())
    ReDim Preserve oData(iLB To iUB)
    oData(iUB) = x
End Sub
Function CreateProperty(sName$, oValue) As com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    Dim oProperty As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    oProperty.Name = sName
    oProperty.Value = oValue
    CreateProperty() = oProperty
End Function
```